# Installing GCC 4.7.0 fails at make command

Tags: linux-mint, make, gcc, cross-compilation

I'm attempting to install GCC 4.7.0 in Linux Mint (based off of Ubuntu 18.04). I get past the first step of configuring it. However when I run `make -j5`, I get the following errors:

```
make[2]: Leaving directory '/home/james/src/build-gcc'
Makefile:26035: recipe for target 'stage1-bubble' failed
make[1]: *** [stage1-bubble] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/james/src/build-gcc'
Makefile:941: recipe for target 'all' failed
make: *** [all] Error 2
make[1]: Entering directory '/home/james/src/build-gcc'
/bin/bash ../gcc-7.4.0/mkinstalldirs /home/james/opt/gcc-7.4.0 
/home/james/opt/gcc-7.4.0
make[2]: Entering directory '/home/james/src/build-gcc/fixincludes'
make[2]: *** No rule to make target 'install'.  Stop.
make[2]: Leaving directory '/home/james/src/build-gcc/fixincludes'
Makefile:3736: recipe for target 'install-fixincludes' failed
make[1]: *** [install-fixincludes] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/james/src/build-gcc'
Makefile:2337: recipe for target 'install' failed
make: *** [install] Error 2
```

I'm following the steps provided by OSDev Wiki here: https://wiki.osdev.org/Building_GCC. I need this compiler to work that so I can make a cross-compiler. Why is this happening and how do I fix it?

EDIT: Here is the full config.log file: http://www.mediafire.com/file/oco5szzfrr7hpmq/config.log/file

Comment: That's the end of the log (omitting most information).  I'd start over and try it without the **`-j5`** option.  If it's not that, determining the actual problem for an old compiler can take a while :-)

Comment: @ThomasDickey I've already tried this, and I still get the same result. I'll see if I can find the full log file. I'll link it in the question when I do.